# How exactly do you do a Laplace Transform of a time delayed signal?

Tags: laplace-transform

We know that the Laplace Transform of a time-delayed signal is $$\mathscr{L} \left[ f(t-a) \cdot u(t-a) \right] = e^{-as} F(s)$$ by definition, but how exactly does that work in practice, say for the general function below? $$f(t)=c_1 t + u(t-a) (c_2(t-a))$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathscr{L}[f(t)](s) 
   &=& \displaystyle 
   \mathscr{L}[c_1t + c_2(t-a)u(t-a)](s) \\ 
   &=& \displaystyle 
   c_1\mathscr{L}[t](s) + c_2e^{-sa}\mathscr{L}[t-a](s) \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   \frac{c_1}{s^2} + c_2e^{-sa}\left(\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{a}{s}\right) \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}$$ refers to? Is it the differential operator, and if so, what is its operand? It should be noted that the 2 in my general function was a typo. It has been changed to what it should be. Essentially, it's just a time-delayed linear function.

Comment: @JacobIvanov  Sorry, I mixed up with Fourier transform; it should be $-\partial_s(1/s) = 1/s^2$. I'll correct it, as well as the factor 2.